# Is there a surviving Jewish translation of the entire Masoretic Text in Greek?

Tags: tanach, translation, mesorah-tradition

Please don't say "the Septuagint" because I know that this has fallen out of favor among most modern Jews (the only exception being Beta Israel, which I believe still uses it - correct me if I am mistaken on that.)

I know that the Torah was translated into Yevanic Greek in 1547 by Romaniote Jews for the "Constantinople Pentateuch," but this is just the first 5 books. Has the remainder of the Masoretic Text been translated into Greek specifically by Jews and specifically for Jewish use?

I also know about the Greek translation by Aquila/Onkelos but this has not survived apart from a few fragments.

Comment: According to this page - on the official GSS Site - https://www.deadseascrolls.org.il/learn-about-the-scrolls/languages-and-scripts?locale=en_US 29 of the Dead Sea Scrolls are in Greek, mostly of Biblical texts.  It also mentions the Nahal Hever Minor Prophets Scroll, which is a Koine Greek version of a good portion of The Twelve, from around the Bar Kochba era.  Even though the Septuagint has not been used by modern Jews, the Hebrew version that was the basis for that translation has been found as one of the "family types" of Tanach manuscripts at Qumran.

Comment: For an interesting read on the "families", look up Frank Moore Cross's article "The Text Behind The Text of The Hebrew Bible".  It's in the Biblical Archaeology Society's Archive, but you have to pay for access...It's also part of the collected articles in their book "Understanding the Dead Sea Scrolls". There might be a free version available on one of the academic websites.

Comment: An interesting aspect of the Nahal Hever Minor Prophets scroll fragments is that even though they are written in Greek(left to right as usual), the 4 letter Name is written in late Paleo-Hebrew characters, from right to left. This can be seen by browsing the fragments on the DSS site.